# Eclipse+PyDev crash

Tags: eclipse, crash, pydev

I use Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Kepler Release 2(Build id: 20140224-0627)and PyDev 3.5 under a virtualenv. 
But when I try to new a python package or .py file. It crashed.... 
Information is:

```
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/chimerahomes/jingtao/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-oracle-1.7.0.55.x86_64/jre/lib/resources.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-oracle-1.7.0.55.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar'
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=7059, tid=47524454697280
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_55-b13) (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.55-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000000000
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in java itself (i.e.: PyDev has no compiled source code, only plain java -- although it's possible it could be in Eclipse too).

My suggestion is trying with a different java 7/8 vm.

Alternatively you can try on LiClipse: http://brainwy.github.io/liclipse/ (which comes with a bundled jvm) -- the only thing is that you may want to install JDT on top of it if you are also working with java.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I reset the virtualenv with python and there is no error now.

Comment: @Jingtao Could you specify this a little bit more? I have the same error and I would like to resolve it. Additional I would like to know if you scheduled a bug report for the JVM or PyDev, because a SIGSEGV should not occur there from my point of view.